# Difference between queue implementations in Python

Tags: python, queue

One of the [exercises](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/BasicDS/ProgrammingExercises.html) (namely, #6) asks us to compare performance of queue implementations (with head in the beinning / at the end of a list). That sounds like there could be some difference, so I tried to figure it out. Here's my code

```
import timeit

class QueueStart(object):
    '''Queue implementation with head in the beginning of a list'''    
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def enqueue(self, i):
        self.items.append(i)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop(0)

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self.items) == 0

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

class QueueEnd(object):
    '''Queue implementation with head at the end of a list'''     
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.items.insert(0, item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self.items) == 0

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

# store results for further plotting
start_add_list = [] # QueueStart.enqueue(item) runtimes for inputs of different sizes
start_pop_list = [] # the same for QueueStart.dequeue(item)
end_add_list = [] # the same for QueueEnd.enqueue(item) 
end_pop_list = [] # the same for QueueEnd.dequeue(item) 

for i in range(100000, 500000, 10000):
    qs = QueueStart()
    qs.items = list(range(i))
    qe = QueueEnd()
    qe.items = list(range(i))
    start_add = timeit.Timer('qs.enqueue(1)', 'from __main__ import qs')
    start_pop = timeit.Timer('qs.dequeue()', 'from __main__ import qs')
    end_add = timeit.Timer('qe.enqueue(1)', 'from __main__ import qe')
    end_pop = timeit.Timer('qe.dequeue()', 'from __main__ import qe')

    start_add_list.append(start_add.timeit(number=1000))
    start_pop_list.append(start_pop.timeit(number=1000))
    end_add_list.append(end_add.timeit(number=1000))
    end_pop_list.append(end_pop.timeit(number=1000))
```

And here are plots that reflect results of my experiment
[image]
[image]

It's known that `insert` and `pop(index)` are O(n). The interesting thing, though, is that from the graphs we see that `insert(0, item)` takes twice as long as `pop(0)`. That observation made me wonder, why this is the case. On the surface, two methods look very similar, but, apparently, under the hood there's something interesting going on. So, the question is: could you help me figure it out?

Comment: This is probably implementation dependent, based on how the operations manage memory as you add and delete to the underlying array. For instance, `insert(0,...)` would need to continuously push everything up one slot, while `pop(0)` could just change which array element is `[0]`, at the cost of having unused memory at the front of the array.

Comment: @chepner: The book the exercise come from says: "When pop is called on the end of the list it takes O(1), but when pop is called on the first element in the list or anywhere in the middle it is O(n). The reason for this lies in how Python chooses to implement lists. **When an item is taken from the front of the list, in Python’s implementation, all the other elements in the list are shifted one position closer to the beginning**." As I understand, both `insert(0, ...)` and `pop(0)` could make tons of shifts in the worst case, but it's not clear where difference by constant factor comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Some reading on CPython's `list` implementation: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/

Basically, lists are designed to have about twice as much memory as they need at any given time, so they can change length slightly without needing to reallocate memory.  When lists need more memory, they sometimes need to move the whole list to another location in memory that has enough space.  When they shrink, they can just free memory at the end of the list.